# searching before adding android

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

i have a book database and the user can add new book into it, but before adding i want to check if this book is in the database or not by the isbn number.. how to do this ?

this is my database helper :

```
   package com.example.mobilib;

   import com.example.mobilib.LoginDataBaseAdapter;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
   import android.util.Log;

   public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DATABASE_NAME="M";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="Book";
public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
public static final String KEY_AUTHOR="author";
public static final String KEY_INFO="info";
public static final String KEY_ISBN="isbn";
public static final String KEY_COPIES="copy";
public static final String KEY_ID="id"; 
static String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_NAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_AUTHOR+" TEXT, "+KEY_INFO+" TEXT, "+KEY_ISBN+" TEXT, "+KEY_COPIES+" TEXT)";

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 

{
    try{
        db.execSQL(LoginDataBaseAdapter.DATABASE_CREATE);          
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }catch( Exception e){
        Log.e("dbAdapter", e.getMessage().toString());
    }

}








@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +oldVersion + " to " +newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);


   }

}
```

and here is my add function :

```
       // saveButton click event 
public void onClick(View v) {
    name=edit_name.getText().toString().trim();
    author=edit_author.getText().toString().trim();
    isbn=edit_isbn.getText().toString().trim();
    copy=edit_copy.getText().toString().trim();
    info=edit_info.getText().toString().trim();
    if(name.length()>0 && author.length()>0 && isbn.length()>0 && copy.length()>0 && info.length()>0)
    {
        saveData();
    }
    else
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminAddBook.this);
        alertBuilder.setTitle("Invalid Data");
        alertBuilder.setMessage("Please, Enter valid data");
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        alertBuilder.create().show();
    }

}

/**
 * save data into SQLite
 */
private void saveData(){
    dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_NAME,name);
    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_AUTHOR,author );
    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_ISBN,isbn );
    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_COPIES,copy );
    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_INFO,info );

    System.out.println("");
    if(isUpdate)
    {    
        //update database with new data 
        dataBase.update(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
    }
    else
    {
        //insert data into database
        dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    //close database
    dataBase.close();
    finish();


}

   }
```

what i want is to search before adding .. if this isbn number is not exist in the database then add it , if its exist then don't save it.

can someone help me please ?
thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function in your healer class to check for existing record on `ISBN` which will return true of false.
call this function before inserting a record , if its return true means record exist else not. If its return false then insert the record.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ......
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(YourActivity.this);
   }
```

in database helper :

```
public boolean isExist(String isbnNo)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query= "select * from TABLE_NAME where KEY_ISBN='"+isbnNo+"' ";      

   Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }

    cursor.close();
    return true;                
}
```

call above function in `saveData()` i.e.

```
private void saveData(){
    dataBase=mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_NAME,name);
    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_AUTHOR,author );
    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_ISBN,isbn );
    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_COPIES,copy );
    values.put(DbHelper.KEY_INFO,info );

    System.out.println("");
    if(isUpdate)
    {    
        //update database with new data 
        dataBase.update(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DbHelper.KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
    }
    else
    {
        //insert data into database
    if(!dbHelper.isExist(isbn)
            dataBase.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    //close database
    dataBase.close();
    finish();


}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response! i tried it and the app will crash when i click on the save button :(

Comment: this is right ? >> '        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());'

Comment: @LamaTatwany yes that is right. If problem not solved then post logcat error message.

Answer (score 0):

Initailize the `DBHelper` in the `onCreate` of your Activity

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(YourActivity.this);
```

your saving functionality

```
// saveButton click event
public void onClick(View v) {
    name = edit_name.getText().toString().trim();
    author = edit_author.getText().toString().trim();
    isbn = edit_isbn.getText().toString().trim();
    copy = edit_copy.getText().toString().trim();
    info = edit_info.getText().toString().trim();
    String existingIsbn = dbHelper.getSinlgeEntry(name);
    // User not exist
    if(existingIsbn.equals("NOT EXIST")){
        //save the data
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry getSingleEntry is not working probably .. i was trying with it and forget to delete it rom my code. isn't there any other solution ?